# CakePHP on MAMP: CakePHP install and WordPress install both in subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

On my local MAMP install, I have a WordPress site, and am trying to get a CakePHP site ( 2.5.6 ) going using their blog tutorial. I want to try CakePHP out and see if it is suitable for a future project.

Interesting portion of folder structure as follows:

```
htdocs
|_ cakePHPBox
|  |_ app
|_ local_blog
```

The WordPress site was originally installed in the root folder. After moving that, I ended up with an .htaccess file in the htdocs root that contained the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cakePHPBox/(.*)$ /cakePHPBox/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cakePHPBox [NC]
RewriteBase /local_blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cakePHPBox [NC]
RewriteRule . /local_blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The .htaccess file in htdocs/cakePHPBox looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /cakePHPBox
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess file in htdocs/cakePHPBox/app looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cakePHPBox
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
```

The .htaccess file in htdocs/cakePHPBox/app/webroot looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /cakePHPBox
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

These are modified from the originals; I am trying to account for the subfolder that CakePHP lives in in all of them, and the one in htdocs is also trying to account for WordPress' subfolder.

The WordPress blog works. The cakePHP tutorial doesn't! CakePHP's "landing page" pulls up without problem.

Trying to access the URL `http://localhost/cakePHPBox/posts/index` as per the tutorial's instructions gives me this error. I can tell there's trouble because it prints the file across the top of the page instead of executing it, but I don't know why that is happening.

[image: Unhappy CakePHP]

Various existing StackOverflow questions and answers have gotten me this far, but now I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear not to have a PostsController.php file in your app/Controller directory. Might that be the case? CakePHP seems to be working up to that point though given the fact that you are getting to app/webroot/index.php.

Comment: That's the part that is confusing me. PostsController.php exists under app/Controller/PostsController.php. And CakePHP is reading it - its contents is displayed right at the top of the page. Why is it reading the file and then not executing it, and complaining that it is missing? It is almost as if it doesn't consider it real PHP script, maybe?

Comment: Ah, that's where the problem was! Two things: some funky encoding ( probably what will happen when you are copying a tutorial example from the internet ) and also something odd: even though apache is set up to treat .php files as PHP, and does so on other folders, it isn't doing so for files inside the CakePHP folder. Thus I needed to add the <?php ?> tags around the code in PostsController.php. I'll have to get to the bottom of that. Your answer was helpful to steer me in the right direction so I'll accept it. Thanks!